# Can't use fat arrow functions (ES6) in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I've had some issues using fat arrow functions in react. If the function is not anonymous, it complains about the syntax and won't compile.

This:

```
handleItemClick = (e, { name }) => this.setState({ activeItem: name });
```

Gives me:

```
BabelLoaderError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (20:20)
```

It points to the equal sign(handleItemClick'=').

This however works just fine:

```
onClick={ (arg) => {//Do something} };
```

Is there something wrong with my webpack config, or something else i'm missing? Thankful for any hints.

```
module.exports = {
  entry: PATHS.app_path,
    output:{
        path: PATHS.build,
        filename: 'index.js'
    },
    devServer:{
        inline: true,
        port: 3333,
        contentBase: PATHS.build,
        publicBase: PATHS.build,
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
    resolve: {
        root: path.resolve('./public'),
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'css-loader',
                query: {
                    modules: true,
                    localIdentName: '[local]'
                    //localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
                }
            },
            { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|jpg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' },
            {
                test: /.*\.svg$/,
                loaders: [
                    'file-loader',
                    'svgo-loader?' + svgoConfig,
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are trying to use [class fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-public-fields), which are not part of ES6, and aren't covered by es2015, and react presets.

You can enable it by using the [Class properties transform babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/):

```
query: {
    presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
    plugins: ["transform-class-properties"]
}
```

Or use the [babel stage-2 preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-2/), that includes the transform plugin:

```
query: {
    presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-2']
}
```

Don't forget to `npm install` the one that you choose.

Comment: Went for the first options, which worked. Will look more into this as it seems I misunderstood the issue. Thank you for the answer! Helped me out a lot.