# Arrow function "this" binding not working in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

As I understand it ES6 arrow functions "preserve `this` context when they are called." I have seen examples in React components using them to bind this in class methods. I know I can bind in the constructor like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getContent = this.getContent.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}
```

But when I try to use an arrow function

```
handleClick = (event) => {
    this.props.openForm();
}
```

I get the following error

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (18:14)

  16 |   }
  17 | 
> 18 |   handleClick = (event) => {
     |               ^
  19 |     this.props.openForm();
  20 |   }
  21 |
```

Why isn't this working?

Here's the full component

```
import React from 'react';
import Section from './Section';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../actions/actions';

class Contact extends React.Component {

  getContent() {
    return this.props.content || {};
  }

  handleClick = (event) => {
    this.props.openForm();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Section heading="Contact" bg="white">

          <div className="contact">

            <h3 className="contact__heading">{ this.getContent().heading }</h3>

            <p>{ this.getContent().text }</p>

            <button className="contact__button contact__btn-dialog" 
                onClick={ this.handleClick }>
              Send a message
            </button>

          </div>

      </Section>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    openForm: () => {
      dispatch(actions.showContactForm(true));
    }
  };
};

export default connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Contact);
```

Comment: Also see on bind vs arrow property, https://stackoverflow.com/a/43601993/3731501

Comment: It isn't concidental that these questions share a topic. Dupe question has *exactly* same problem, and [the cause and the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41464305/3731501) should be same, too. Consider re-asking the question with updated details if the solution suggested in dupe question didn't work for you.

Comment: I was looking at the link in the comments  stackoverflow.com/a/43601993/3731501 I later saw the link at the top and realized the error.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare the method as arrow function you don't need to bind it in the constructor.

In this case, use either `bind` or arrow function directly and not both.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }

  handleClick() {
     console.log('with constructor')
  }
  
  handleClick2 = (event) => {
    console.log('without constructor')
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>With constructor</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick2}>Without constructor</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I do not have it in the constructor, if you will look at the full component in the OP. `this` evaluates to null. I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of null"

Comment: @mhatch Please check my sample code. Maybe that helps :)